# aliasmatch regex woes

Tags: regex, apache, sitemap

I'm working on trying to get our site's sitemapping functioning.  I was given the task of getting a script running which propagates several files out to said servers in the format of:

a sitemap.xml file which points to --> several sitemap_10001_?.xml.gz files
These files are stored in a location of /webfiles/sitemap/example/

The sitemap.xml file points to those files as:

```
example.com/webapp/wcs/stores/sitemap_10001_1.xml.gz  (or 10001_2, _3, etc).
```

The problem I'm having is I slapped together a regex to evaluate incoming requests for sitemap_*.xml.gz  and point them in what I thought would be the proper direction.

```
AliasMatch ^/sitemap_(.*).xml.gz        "/webfiles/sitemap/example/sitemap_$1.xml.gz"
```

At this point as best as I can figure, this regex is failing miserably.

Nothing in the error log, just an access log entry of:

> 1.2.3.4 - - [09/Oct/2015:01:30:04 -0400] "GET /webapp/wcs/stores/sitemap_10001_2.xml.gz HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36" "1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.4"  4002 "1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.4" "-" www.example.com internalsitename:9085 "http://www.example.com/GenericApplicationError"

Any assistance fixing the crafted regex would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you need to escape the literal dots and slash? `^\/sitemap_(.*)\.xml\.gz`

Comment: Not sure.  The basis of what I used was: AliasMatch ^/icons(.*) /usr/local/apache/icons$1  from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html.  I also crafted the regex with the help of: http://www.regexr.com/ and was able to make: sitemap_(.*).xml.gz work there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a dot (`.`) in RegEx is used to match any character apart from a new line character. You need to escape these 'special' characters, usually with the use of a backslash. You might also want to use an end of line anchor:

```
AliasMatch ^/sitemap_(.*)\.xml\.gz$ /webfiles/sitemap/example/sitemap_$1.xml.gz
```

Comment: So I'm going to mark this as correct though in the end my boss ended up finding the issue which ironically wasn't with the regex but rather how the script processing had handled the actual sitemap manifest and the way the httpd.conf file was processing the sitemap.xml contents.  Thanks for the prompt responses macroman.

Comment: I should also mention he pointed out my regex was 'functionally valid, though technically incorrect'.  For example, adding .xml.gz means it'd match anything where the .'s were, including the .'s themselves.  Your answer is the proper syntax to ensure completeness.

Comment: In terms of real-world use yes, your original regex wouldn't be a problem. The point made about escaping character literals was just for the sake of 'best practice' really. :)